# Does a master's research project (not a thesis) count as a "publication" for PhD applications?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions, thesis, publishers

My [master's in mathematical finance](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/with-a-background-in-mathematical-finance-and-desire-to-apply-for-a-mathematics) doesn't have a "thesis" exactly, but it has a research project where we helped a bank develop a model to help with credit risk by identifying which variables were more important in credit risk management (based on the particular data set we had which was the financial information, such as net income or return on assets, of the clients of the bank). This wasn't some report at the end of an internship, so our research project is somewhere in the middle of an internship and a thesis, I think.

My coauthors and I printed out a document that had an abstract, review of related literature, scope, methodology, etc which was then put in hard bounds and is now sitting on the shelves in the math department of my university.

We gave the first/a mock presentation to the risk management department and then the second/a real presentation to our "thesis" advisers.

The document is about the application of some articles, journals, papers, etc that led to us developing a model.

In a PhD application form, I'm asked for any publishing. Does the "thesis" count as a "publication" ? If so, is the "publisher" the university?

The options for type of publication are:

"Books/Book Chapter, Conference Paper, Journal Publications, Others"

The options for status of publication are:

"Published, Not yet - accepted in press, Not yet - Under review, Not yet - writing in progress"

Comment: Is it really *public*? Is it available online?  If not, could any person off the street come and read it?  Would your university send someone a copy upon request (and payment of copying fees)?  And is it written with the scientific community as an audience, or would it only be useful to the client?

Comment: You might be able to list it as a [technical report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_report), if it seems to fit that definition.  Note that however you list it, it is going to carry much less weight than a peer-reviewed paper.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge. Nice to see your username again. Your comments are always appreciated. I believe it would be useful to the scientific community as an audience. I don't believe this is a report, although we did report. I edited the question. I apologize for any confusion and highly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Requirements vary between countries and universities, without further details this question would not be answerable.

Comment: @JackBauer: Be aware that a *technical report* is not necessarily comparable to a student *internship/project report*. The latter are *reports* in that they actually report on what happened during the internship/project, often including secondary factors such as describing team dynamics, the concrete internship arrangements, "background info" on how much time was spent on acquiring which skills, etc. A *technical report*, on the other hand, can be [virtually indistinguishable from a paper](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/handle/1903/373) except for not having been published in a peer-reviewed venue.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sorry I forgot to delete my comment after I stupidly commented before reading the wikipedia page. Thank you! :)

Comment: @NateEldredge Never mind. Thank you! :) How about posting as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If it's printed in your institution's library it is fair to say that it was published by your university. You may want to explicitly list it as a technical report in your bibliography to clarify the type of publication that it is (your audience will want to know if your publications are peer reviewed or not).

Under the list you have here it would be an "Other" that is "Published".

Answer (score 0):

If I read that application form, I would not consider what you have as a *publication*. I do not consider my *doctoral* thesis to be a publication. The publications are the papers that make up the thesis, intended for peer-reviewed journals. (In other fields 'journal' might not be the appropriate format necessarily, but the principle holds.)

You work should, however, appear somewhere on you application form, just not in this particular box.