# Where can I find academic CV samples containing minor research projects for PhD applications without publications?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, cv

Context:

- Prof messaged me, [interested in my CV](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79539/)
- During my [master's](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/with-a-background-in-mathematical-finance-and-desire-to-apply-for-a-mathematics) in mathematical finance, I may have had [one "publication"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78356/does-a-masters-research-project-not-a-thesis-count-as-a-publication-for-phd) if a quasi-thesis, that wasn't exactly a thesis, counts.
- While applying to [(more) grad school](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79539) (pure not applied), I'm currently working in the tutoring industry (I'm not teaching in a university) as I have been since grad school (tutoring industry is very serious in [country A compared to country B](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75677)), and my industry CVs/resumes consist mainly of tutoring jobs (I've never had a finance internship, but I did have a sort of statistics/economics research internship).

I do not believe I have formal pure math research experience, but I have a lot of applied math research experience in our "thesis" (or technical report as Nate Eldredge might suggest) and class projects.

I have so far not found academic CVs for PhD applications that include minor research projects in master's (I don't know the terms. They are "research" projects but are not published or as long as theses. They're simply class requirements that are not exams or "homework"/"problem sets") so please provide references.

Examples:

1. [UTexas - Ella Fitzsimmons](http://ugs.utexas.edu/sites/default/files/ugs/docs/Sample%20CV_0.pdf)

   - GOOD: has master's, no PhD
   - BAD: thesis only. no minor research projects in master's here.
2. [UCSF - Rembrandt Van Rijn](https://career.ucsf.edu/sites/career.ucsf.edu/files/PDF/ResearcherResearchPackage2.pdf)

   - GOOD: mentions minor research projects pre-PhD
   - BAD: has PhD and so mentions minor research projects pre-PhD without further elaboration
3. [Academics - Anna Mustermann](https://www.academics.com/science/apply-for-a-phd-how-to-write-your-cv_57279.html)

   - GOOD: has master's no PhD
   - BAD: For master's: thesis only. no minor research projects in master's here. has publications
4. [Surrey - ROBERT BROADSTONE](https://www.surrey.ac.uk/careers/documents/applications/cv_academic.pdf)

   - BAD: No master's. Has PhD. Has publications
5. [Harvard - Anjan Lo Subramayan, Keisha Thomas](http://ocs.fas.harvard.edu/files/ocs/files/gsas-just-for-scientists-cvs-resumes.pdf)

   - BAD: Has PhD/Is PhD candidate, No master's, Has publications

Comment: Wait.  What?  "if a thesis (it wasn't a thesis) counts"?  I don't get it.

Comment: @aparente001 It sort of functions like a thesis in other courses in that we had review of related literature, methodology and all of that. We even called. but technically it wasn't

Comment: It's YOUR cv. Especially in academia you can pretty much put on it whatever you want. You should definately include your minor research projects. But "publications" usually only count if they are published in international peer-reviewed journals. It may be viewed as strange if you try to include anything else as a "publication".

Comment: @LouicVermeer Thank you so much! Why don't you post that as an answer? Also I edited my question :)

Comment: @aparente001 I edited my question. :)

Comment: Are these research projects that are class assignments novel work, or are they research in the sense of searching the literature on a particular topic? If the latter, this does not seem to fall under "research" in the sense the word is typically used in academia (though I am speaking from a biological sciences perspective; maybe literature review is given a different type of value in mathematics that I am unaware of).

Comment: If a professor asks you for more information about you, just give him or her an accurate picture of yourself.  S/he's probably asking in order to get an accurate view of where you are in your journey.  Not necessarily using the response in order to weed out potential students.  (It's possible I have completely misunderstood your question, though.)

Comment: @BryanKrause Some are [expository I guess](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49595/is-it-common-for-an-undergraduate-thesis-in-pure-mathematics-to-prove-something/49614), some are RRL, and some are applying what we learn to data we choose like copulas on recent financial data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to follow a standard or template unless the specific job you apply for explicitly states that you should do so (which is rarely the case).

I am a biophysicist, not a mathematician, but from what I have seen you can put on *your* CV whatever you want, especially in academia: it is *your* CV. You should definitely include your minor research projects. You can have a look at templates for some inspiration but it is up to you how you organise your CV and which sections you include or not.

Publications usually only count if they are published in international peer-reviewed journals or books. You can possibly stretch this definition a little by including conference proceedings, abstracts, application notes, and so on, but it may be viewed as strange if you call these a "publication" (mathematicians, please correct me if this is different for you). In any case, this is the topic of your [other question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78356/does-a-masters-research-project-not-a-thesis-count-as-a-publication-for-phd) and is better discussed there.