# Indicate leadership/groupwork in research experience for graduate applications?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv, soft-skills

For academic CVs, should/how do/how might I indicate leadership/group work when describing certain research projects?

- Option A: Use words

> Project A, Subject X11, Date
>
> Group
>
> Description
>
> Project B, Subject X12, Date
>
> Individual
>
> Description
>
> Project C, Subject X12, Date
>
> Group, Leader
>
> Description

- Option B: Use letters

> Key:
>
> G for Group but not leader
>
> I for Individual
>
> L for Group Leader
>
> ---
>
> Project A, Subject X11, Date, G
>
> Description
>
> Project B, Subject X12, Date, I
>
> Description
>
> Project C, Subject X12, Date, L
>
> Description

- Option C: Do not indicate on academic CV, but describe in application how many research projects are included, how many were by group and how many were led
- Option D: Other

---

Couldn't find any [samples/templates](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/81540/) with clear indications or articles discussing such or maybe I missed in the templates or articles I've already read.

If the answer may vary, please indicate source of variance eg depends on whether or it's not for PhD applications. Then pretty please provide conditional answers. =)

---

### Contexts:

see revision history

Comment: Could you indicate that you were the group leader in the project description?

Comment: @Dawn How is that different from option A please?

Comment: Don't use option B, it is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the via negativa I guess @Davidmh. How do you suggest communicating this in a non confusing way?

Comment: @JackBauer I don't have a good way. It is uncommon to include this kind of information in normal situations, but I see your point in including it.

Comment: @Davidmh What's a non confusing way even if [not good as long as not bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YeulUgWNp8)? =)

Comment: @JackBauer I don't review PhD applications, so I prefer not to give you an answer that may be wrong. You could ask one of your professor, since they will be the ones reviewing them, and more familiar with the details.

Comment: Just keep it as clear and as short as you can. The key point here is to make it easy to understand for the reader. Giving too much detail is not good. Giving too little is not good either. Use common sense, and let a friend (or supervisor) check your CV when it is done.

Comment: I am assuming that Option A includes some sort of bulleted text in the description. If so, you can include phrases like "Led a group of ...." The description can cover not only the project but also your role. This would eliminate the need for an additional line. Or, you could include the names of group members with (Project lead) after the lead. This more closely mimics how papers are shown. I agree that Option B is bad because interpreting a key requires more work by the leader. It is not a lot of work, but reviewers have to go through so many documents, any additional work irritates them.

Comment: @Dawn I was thinking 'Led a group of ....' because I guess that's how I would say it if this were a job application. The thing is the local government is looking for leadership and interpersonal. Sooo it also seems like additional work if the reader would want to count how many projects were by group and how many of those were led by me? Please and thanks!

Comment: @louic The thing is the local government is looking for leadership and interpersonal. Sooo it also seems like additional work if the reader would want to count how many projects were by group and how many of those were led by me? Please and thanks!

Comment: @Davidmh Ok thanks. Btw, are you opinionless for the other options?

Comment: You can always include it like A (or my modified A) on the CV and then also tally it up in the personal statement or letter. I don't think it has to be an either/or.

Comment: @Dawn Good idea. thanks! Post as answer?

Comment: @Davidmh What do you think of Dawn's suggestion? Say 'Led a group...' but then also tally it up